# Inside for loop 'request function' is being executed 5 times only for last 'if else' statement and skipping previous conditions

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am new in node.js. I have written a program to fetch Urls of free apps on playstore. The code is intended get URLs from 5 pages based on different languages. Such as `en`, `gb`, `au`, `de`, `es`. But I am confused about **request() function**. it is only picking URL inside  last 'if else' statement and skipping previous conditions for all 5 iterations. that is:

```
 `$url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free?hl=es";`
```

its displays same URL for all 5 iteration. **request() function** is picking same URL for all iterations because for loop iterates only for `'$state == 5)'`  I am new in coding so I request you to bear me.  I am attaching output for clarification. where I am mistaken ? please help

[image]

> Output after adding 
>   `console.log("finished state................."+$state); console.log($url);`
>   out of request module aslo.

[image]

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

for ($state = 1; $state <=5; $state++) {
        if ($state == 1)
        {            
            $c_code = 'us';
            $url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free?hl=us";
            //console.log("finished................."+$state);
        } 
        else if($state == 2)

        {
            $c_code = 'gb';
            $url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free?hl=gb";
            //console.log("finished................."+$state);
        } 
        else if($state == 3)
        {
            $c_code = 'de';
            $url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free?hl=de";
            //console.log("finished................."+$state);
        } 
        else if ($state == 4)
        {
            $c_code = 'au';
            $url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free?hl=au";
           // console.log("finished................."+$state);
        } 
        else if ($state == 5)
        {
            $c_code = 'es';
            $url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free?hl=es";
            //console.log("finished................."+$state);
        }
//console.log($url);  
//console.log("finished................."+$state);

request({
    uri: $url}, function (error, response, html) {
    //https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const allLinks = [];
    //console.log($url);
    $countInsertedLinks = 0;
    $uniqInsertedData = 0;

        $(".cover > a").each(function () {

        const link = $(this);
        const text = link.text();
        const href = link.attr('href');
        const app_full_url = href;
        const app_id = app_full_url.split("=");
        allLinks.push(app_id[1]);
        //console.log(href);
    }); 

    for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
     // console.log(allLinks[i]);

    } 

    console.log($url);
    console.log("finished state................."+$state);

}); // request function



//console.log("finished state................."+$state);
//console.log($url);


} //for loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is scoping: you have not explicitly declared these vars:

```
for (let $state = 1; $state <= 5; $state++) {
  // if you define your var like this, your script will works
  let $c_code;
  let $url;
  let $countInsertedLinks;
  let $uniqInsertedData;
  ...
```

so they are `var` in the global scope because of [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

I strongly suggest you to use the [`'use strict'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) mode in your javascript files. This will help you a lot.

I would also suggest a different approach for this task;

```
'use strict';

const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const langs = ['us', 'gb', 'de', 'au', 'es'];


let total = 0;
const myCounter = (num) => {
  total += num;
  console.log(`My total is ${total}`);
};

langs.forEach((url, index) => callUrl(url, index, myCounter));

function callUrl(lang, idCall, cb) {
  request({ uri: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free?hl=${lang}` },
    (error, response, html) => {
    // https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      const allLinks = [];
      $('.cover > a').each(function () {
        const link = $(this);
        const text = link.text();
        const href = link.attr('href');
        const app_full_url = href;
        const app_id = app_full_url.split('=');
        allLinks.push(app_id[1]);
        // console.log(href);
        cb(1);
      });

      console.log(`finished state.................${idCall}`);
    });
}
```